# Sending UDP packet from iPhone to PC via WLAN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, udp, send

After reading several tutorials I came up with the following code:
(Using the famous GCDAsyncUdpSocket class)

```
NSError *error = nil;

if (![mSocket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.111" onPort:9050 error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", [error description]);
}

usleep(100000);

NSString* str = @"teststring";
[mSocket sendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] toHost:@"192.168.1.111" port:9050 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

If I run this code on my iPhone everything seems fine (no errors).
But the packet never arrives on my PC.

On my PC a UDP listener is running (alongside with Wireshark). Both devices are on the same network with the same subnet and similar IPs (my PC is 192.168.1.111). Am I doing something wrong? A simple mistake hopefully?

Comment: Have you set the delegate for that socket? Is it calling didConnectToHost?

Comment: No, I did not implement the delegate (is that required?). But I checked the "isConnected" property after calling connect. That was set to TRUE.

Comment: Well, in theory is not required, but there might be an issue with not setting the delegate, as it is not the common scenario and might not have been thoroughly tested. I'd quickly implement it and would give it a go to see if it fixes anything.

Comment: After I call "sendData " the callbacks "didSendDataWithTag"/"didNotSendDataWithTag" are not called. I think at least one of them should be called, right?

Comment: Yes, they should. I'd go into GCDAAsyncSocket code and would set a few breakpoints there to see what's going on. Also, try the non GCD version and see if it makes any better.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan ;-)  Non GCD? Where would I find such a thing?

Comment: According to the documentation in the header file, `sendData:toHost:...` cannot be used with a connected socket. Try if it works if you omit the `connectToHost:` call.

Comment: Yehaw! I think that solved it :-)

Comment: Good! I will post it as an answer, so that you can accept if you have verified that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods

```
sendData:toHost:port:withTimeout:tag:
sendData:toAddress:withTimeout:tag:
```

are for sending messages with *unconnected* sockets, so you should not call `connectToHost`. For a connected host, you can use

```
sendData:withTimeout:tag:
```